# testng-failed.xml does not contain methods with always run = true

Tags: testng

Lets say I have two classes

```
Class A
{
     @BeforeClass
     public void abc()
     {
        ----
     }
     @Test(alwaysRun = true)
     public void def()
     {
        -----
     }
}
```

And another class

```
Class B
{
    @Test
    public void xyz()
    {
         SoftAssert sa = new SoftAssert();
         -----
         sa.fail();
         sa.assertAll();
    }
}
```

Lets Say Class B has failed
Then testng-failed.xml will be craeted as follows

```
<test name="test1(failed)">
<classes>
  <class name="A">
    <methods>
      <include name="abc"/>
    </methods>
  </class>

   <class name="B">
    <methods>
      <include name="xyz"/>
    </methods>
  </class>
```

I have mentioned always run = true for the method def as true, then that method must also included in testng-failed.xml.

Why was that not present in the testng-failed.xml?

Comment: Maybe it runs correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition `alwaysRun` attribute on a `@Test` method indicates the following (quoting the javadocs)

> If set to true, this test method will always be run even if it depends
>   on a method that failed.

By behavior, TestNG includes only those methods that failed in the `testng-failed.xml`. So if your `def()` method didn't fail, then it wont be included in your `testng-failed.xml`.

If you would like the `def()` method to be included all the time (which then am guessing, its not a `@Test` method but seems to be more of a configuration method), then you have the following options.

1. Move it out of an @Test method (because it looks like it really is not a test method but some sort of a conditional setup that needs to be done only for certain methods) and into a TestNG listener [ for e.g., an `org.testng.IInvokedMethodListener` ] and within the listener have this get executed based on some custom annotation. So all methods that needs this special code snippet to be run, would add a custom annotation [ See [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-custom-annotations-example/) for an example]
   and within this listener's `beforeInvocation()` you would look for the custom annotation and if found, you would run it.
2. The other option would basically be to have this part of a base class which implements `org.testng.IHookable` interface. All your test methods would extend this base class and within the run() implementation of the base class [ run() method via IHookable interface ] you would add the same custom annotation logic that I mentioned above.​

Here's a sample that shows all of this in action.

**Sample for (1)**

**The marker annotation.**

```java
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;

/**
 * A marker annotation that indicates a special setup is needed.
 */
@Retention(java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD})
public @interface NeedSpecialSetup {}
```

```java
/**
 * This interface which when implemented by test classes (classes that hold one or more {@link org.testng.annotations.Test}
 * annotated methods lets you perform special actions. But the methods should also be annotated using {@link NeedSpecialSetup}
 * annotation for this implementation to be invoked.
 */
public interface PerformSpecialSetup {
    void perform();
}
```

**The listener**

```java
import org.testng.IInvokedMethod;
import org.testng.IInvokedMethodListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

public class SimpleMethodListener implements IInvokedMethodListener {
    @Override
    public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
        //Did the method have our custom annotation which indicates that special setup is needed ?
        NeedSpecialSetup specialsetup = method.getTestMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod().getAnnotation(NeedSpecialSetup.class);
        if (specialsetup != null) {
            //Now lets check if the Object to which the method belongs to, has the capability to do the special setup
            //and if it does, just delegate the call back to the respective test class instance. This way, we are not
            //hard wiring any logic to our listener, but letting the respective test classes do whatever custom
            //setup it requires.
            Object instance = testResult.getInstance();
            if (instance instanceof PerformSpecialSetup) {
                ((PerformSpecialSetup) instance).perform();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) { }
}
```

**The test class**

```java
import org.testng.annotations.Listeners;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Listeners(SimpleMethodListener.class)
public class MyTestClass implements PerformSpecialSetup {

    @Test
    public void method1() {
        System.err.println("method1() invoked");
    }

    @Test
    @NeedSpecialSetup
    public void method2() {
        System.err.println("method2() invoked");
    }

    @Override
    public void perform() {
        System.err.println("Special setup completed");
    }
}
```

**Sample for (2)**

```java
import org.testng.IHookCallBack;
import org.testng.IHookable;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class AnotherTestClass implements IHookable {
    @Override
    public void run(IHookCallBack callBack, ITestResult testResult) {
        NeedSpecialSetup specialsetup = testResult.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod().getAnnotation(NeedSpecialSetup.class);
        if (specialsetup != null) {
            perform();
        }
        callBack.runTestMethod(testResult);
    }

    @Test
    public void method1() {
        System.err.println("method1() invoked");
    }

    @Test
    @NeedSpecialSetup
    public void method2() {
        System.err.println("method2() invoked");
    }

    public void perform() {
        System.err.println("Special setup completed");
    }
}
```